# Trigger a Jenkins job when a PR is created on bitbucket. The PR Should run on source branch

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

Is it possible to run a Jenkins pipeline when an PR is created in Bitbucket.
The Pipeline should run for the source branch.
If PR is raised from feature to master. The pipeline should run the Jenkinsfile of feature branch.

The Jenkins should trigger a job that will automatically detect the source branch and run a job for source branch.
Even if 100 PRs are raised it should automatically detect the source branches and run Jekinsfile of the source branches itself.

Note: All feature branches will start with feature_****.

Please help me by suggesting an answer or any useful resource to implement the above requirement.

Comment: What you are describing is exactly the [Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/), have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Running a job by detecting each PR is fairly simple. However, running it based on the Jenkinsfile of the branch is not going to be so straightforward. This is because the Jenkinsfile is used to kick off the rest of the pipeline, so once it starts, the stages and steps can't be changed.

As for detecting PR's you could either use the Bitbucket plugin and incoming webhooks if your Bitbucket instance is able to access your Jenkins instance. If not, you can create a polling job that runs every couple of minutes and checks to see if a new PR has been created (or if an existing PR has a new commit). If there is, you start a Jenkins build. At the end of the Jenkins build, use the Bitbucket API to set the build status of the latest commit to success or fail (depending on the job result). Then the next time the PRs are polled you can use this status to see if the last commit has been build.